# Animate Clip rect height and width

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I need to animate Heigth and Width of the Clip Rect using Story, If I write like below code

```
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(RectangleGeometry.Rect).Height" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="55"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Designer crash and says Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.Clip).(RectangleGeometry.Rect).Height.

How to overcome this !!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Animating its Width/Height is not the best idea since those are dependent properties. I'd use a `ScaleTransform` on the `RectangleGeometry` and animate that. You should be able to name the transform and target the transform directly instead of using complicated target property paths. If that doesn't work - I'd set the target in code behind.

Comment: your answer will work, I tried it. But why the reason we could'nt animate Height and Width of the Clip Rect ??

Comment: Because that will require the animation to be dependent animation that runs on UI thread and is then a lot slower and uglier than an independent animation.

Comment: I do understand the animation might not be smooth, and is dependent on the rendering engine. But why does it crashes saying cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.Clip).(RectangleGeometry.Rect).Height.

Comment: I'm not sure. The intricacies of the binding paths often elude me, but I think if you parenthesize (a.b) then you are asking for an attached property *b* defined in type *a* and `Clip` and `Rect` are not attached properties.

Comment: If my approach is wrong means, How can I animate exact Height and width property for clip rect in xaml, not using Transforms.